# MySQL, PHP, jSON append data from MySQL into an array in PHP and converting in jSON file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a little problem to code in PHP how to obtain this result with data provided from MySQL

```
{"profiles":[
{"ID": "39780b57-9181-4a41-a31e-5d4b3fa59a50", "Name": "Mihai - BP Dev Team","CountryCode": "ro","PictureID": "a30d750a-38e6-407f-a722-943fe3711807","IsStandard": true,"IsOnline": true,"IsPremium": true,"IsVerified": true,"Age": 27,"CityStateCode": "Bucharest"},
{"ID": "e1dd5bab-1eeb-4729-a4f6-0baeb851f750", "Name": "Nicolai", "CountryCode": "dk", "PictureID": "af1345b5-8380-4300-abf0-1d5f15c90040", "IsStandard": true, "Age": 32, "CityStateCode": "Valby"},
{"ID": "2c8535ec-25a4-4a3e-a333-c3797aff491f", "Name": "Testing", "CountryCode": "ca", "PictureID": "ba44bf9b-1592-40a8-b60c-068603bfb9c1", "IsStandard": true, "Age": 30, "CityStateCode": "Centre-Sud North"}}
]}
```

This is my PHP code :

```
$accessDb = new Connexion("gaiurba_MyBD");
$connexion2 = $accessDb->openConnexion(); 

if ($query2 = $connexion2->prepare("SELECT u.UserName as UserName, u.PictureID as PictureID, u.CountryCode as CountryCode,
                                                       u.DateOfBirth as DateOfBirth, u.CityCode as CityCode, u.VerifiedTimestamp as VerifiedTimestamp,
                                                       u.OnlineStatus as OnlineStatus, u.IsPaying as IsPaying, u.StatusAvailableForDates as StatusAvailableForDates,
                                                       cc.$languageCode as CityStateCode, os.$languageCode as LabelOnlineStatus
                                                  FROM Users u
                                            INNER JOIN CityCode cc ON u.CityCode = cc.id
                                            INNER JOIN OnlineStatus os ON u.OnlineStatus = os.id
                                                 WHERE u.ID =  ?")) {
                $query2->bind_param('s', $id);
                $query2->execute();
                $query2->bind_result($UserName, $PictureID, $CountryCode, $DateOfBirth, $CityStateCode, $VerifiedTimestamp, $OnlineStatus, $IsPaying, $StatusAvailableForDates, $CityStateCode, $LabelOnlineStatus);
                $query2->store_result();

                $affected2 = $connexion2->affected_rows;

                // TRACE
                echo "[affected2 row 2 = $affected2]";

                if ($affected2 == 1) {
                    while ($query2->fetch()) {
                        echo "[ID = $id - UserName = $UserName - PictureID = $PictureID - CountryCode = $CountryCode - DateOfBirth = $DateOfBirth - CityStateCode = $CityStateCode - VerifiedTimestamp = $VerifiedTimestamp - OnlineStatus = $OnlineStatus - IsPaying = $IsPaying - StatusAvailableForDates = $StatusAvailableForDates - CityStateCode = $CityStateCode - LabelOnlineStatus = $LabelOnlineStatus]";
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = '{"exception":false,"success":false,"status":0,"message":"ERROR SQL Query : SELECT-ULL-ID Number of row !","confirmMessage":null,"html":null,"data":null}';
                }
            } else {
                $result = '{"exception":false,"success":false,"status":0,"message":"ERROR SQL Query : SELECT-ULL-ID Number of row !","confirmMessage":null,"html":null,"data":null}';
            }
```

I know the right code is on my while($query2->fetch()) condition because my echo see me good information read from my BD. The first thing i need to create an array in PHP and append each row fetched from BD and at the end use

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Do not pay attention to my data return by me SELECT and the data in the JSON string.  I know I'll have to format some data in my while loop to get the right result.

I just need to know how to create an array in which I add a new array for each rows returned by MySQL.

Thank you for your helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an array is as simple as:

```
$profiles = array();
```

or just

```
// Add an item. Array is created if $x didn't contain an array already.
$profiles[] = 'foo';
```

So to create something with the structure you like, you'll need an object with a property that contains an array of objects representing the rows.

You can create a simple object in a similar fashion as arrays: just start assigning properties. So to create the array of profiles, just do this for each row:

```
$profile = null;
$profile->UserName = $UserName;
$profile->PictureID = $PictureID;
// Etc
```

Maybe your database class supports a method to return an entire row as an object instead of calling `fetch()` combined with outbound parameters. That way you don't need to create the object yourself, saving a couple of lines.

```
// Add profile object to array.
$profiles[] := $profile;
```

Maybe your database class supports a way to return the entire dataset as an array of objects. If so, you don't need to loop and build the array yourself. Saving yet another couple of lines of code.

However you have built the array, afterwards, wrap it in another object, in its `profiles` property to be precise.

```
$result = null;
$result->profiles = $profiles;
```

And output:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

It's not strictly necessary to make a variable `null` before starting to assign properties, but it prevents accidental reuse of an old variable. Especially in the loop this is required, otherwise you'll just reassign the properties of the same object and add the same object a number of times to the array, leading to undesired results (every row being the same).

Instead of just assigning properties, you can actually create an object before doing so:

```
$profile = new StdClass();
```

This is a little more verbose and therefor maybe a little more readable, just as using `array()` to initialize an empty array. It's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explainations ! in NetBeans i have an Syntax error on line : $profiles[] := $profile;  I use your declaration $profile = new StdClass(); and for $profiles = new StdClass();

Comment: `$profiles` should not be an object but an array. `new StdClass()` should work fine, but I think the parentheses are optional since there are not parameters to the constructor. See also: [Dynamic Properties in PHP and StdClass](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass)